# Yii2: How to do a inner join of three tables?

Tags: join, activerecord, yii2

I have a many-to-many relationship so I have three tables (**administrators**, **offices** and the **intermediate table**):

[image: 2]

I need to do a very simple **innerjoin** of the three tables to show **lastnames** and their **offices** with [Active Record](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record). I tried but I couldn't.

This is what I tried:

```
$admins = Admins::find()
    ->joinWith(Oficinas::tableName())
    ->all();

echo '<pre>';
print_r($admins);
echo '</pre>';
die();
```

Also I would like to know how to show the SQL query so it can help me to find a solution.

Comment: what have you tried, add your query

Comment: `joinWith` is used for relations you need to specify relation name not the table name

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Make your post self-contained. Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code & desired output & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the relation name for `joinWith()` rather than table names. Since there isn't any info on the relation names I will use simple `innerJoin` using table names as per your requirements to display the last name and the office name for the admins.

```
Admins::find()
->alias('a')
->select('a.lastnameadm, o.nombreofi')
->innerJoin('admin_oficinas ao','ao.idadm = a.idadm')
->innerJoin('oficinas o','o.idofi = ao.idofi')
->all();
```

Answer (score 1):

### Try this:

```
TABLE_NAME_1::find()
   ->join('inner join', 
               'table_name_2',
               'table_name_2.column = table_name_1.column'
           ); 
   ->join('inner join', 
               'table_name_3',
               'table_name_3.column = table_name_2.column'
           )->all();
```

but if you can also use Via like the following example:

```
public function getClassschedule()
{
    return $this->hasOne(TABLE_NAME_2::className(), ['table_name_1.column' => 'table_name_2.column'])
        ->via('tableName3');
}
```

when excuded, the results should be obtained like the previous example. so there's no need to repeated relations. full documentation can be seen here :
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record